# How do I post an object array to Controller like json data via ajax

Tags: c#, json, list, object, controller

I have a model like

```
[DataContract]
public class module_shortcut_order
{
    [DataMember]
    public int MODULE_ID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int LINE_ORDER { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string USER_ID { get; set; }

}
```

And I have a controller which use model list like

```
public JsonResult sortUpdate(List<module_shortcut_order> process)
    {
        ...processing...
    }
```

and also I have Ajax script to post model list

```
parms = { "process": [{ "MODULE_ID": "10", "LINE_ORDER": "0", "USER_ID": "12354" }, 
{ "MODULE_ID": "5", "LINE_ORDER": "1", "USER_ID": "32154" }] };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../Home/sortUpdate",
    dataType: "json",
    data: parms,
    success: function (data) {

        ... do something ...

    }

});
```

Javascript works but object array doesnt fill controler list modal
When it run model fill objects as much as array count but their properties 0 or null

Comment: So you're saying when you change`List<module_shortcut_order> process` to type `object[]` your properties from your `ajax` POST don't get serialized?

Comment: I post 3 objects from ajax. I can see 3 objects on process but properties 0(int) or null(string)